# Computing the energy of a signal over 30 second periods in Python

Tags: python, lambda, signal-processing, fft

I'm new both to Python and to signal processing, so pardon possible misuse of jargon.

I have the discrete values of a signal in a Pandas dataframe x, spaced 1 second apart. It looks like this:

```
2017-08-02 16:42:00  0.363657
2017-08-02 16:42:01  0.282907
2017-08-02 16:42:02  0.155929
...
2017-08-02 16:43:14  0.178522
2017-08-02 16:43:15  0.488507
2017-08-02 16:43:16  0.194987
...
```

I would like to compute the energy of the signal over 30 second periods (by energy I mean the sum of squares of the discrete Fourier coefficients, normalized by the number of summands). I would like the output to be of the form

```
2017-08-02 16:42:00  x_1
2017-08-02 16:42:30  x_2
2017-08-02 16:43:00  x_3
...
```

where each x_i is a scalar corresponding to the energy for that 30s period. I'm also fine with getting a numpy array, as eventually I only need the energy values and not the time stamps.

I tried doing this:

```
energy = x.resample('30S').apply(lambda x: (numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.fft(x))**2)/30)
```

however, I get something of the form

```
2017-08-02 16:42:00    [[0.422450491863], [0.482244793857], [0.514463...
2017-08-02 16:42:30    [[0.345172558059], [0.554558388074], [0.461898...
2017-08-02 16:43:00    [[0.689816890284], [0.613620822242], [0.389962...
```

What did I do wrong, and how would be best to correct it?

Thanks!

**EDIT: I changed the time a bit as I needed to copy only a small portion of the output, so don't mind the values themselves.**

**EDIT 2: The code appears exactly as written here, namely:

```
x = 2017-08-02 16:42:00  0.363657
    2017-08-02 16:42:01  0.282907
    2017-08-02 16:42:02  0.155929
    ...
    2017-08-02 16:43:14  0.178522
    2017-08-02 16:43:15  0.488507
    2017-08-02 16:43:16  0.194987
    ...
#This is imported as a dataframe, and indeed shows its type as pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

energy = x.resample('30S').apply(lambda x: (numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.fft(x))**2)/30)

Out: energy = 2017-08-02 16:42:00    [[0.422450491863], [0.482244793857], [0.514463...
2017-08-02 16:42:30    [[0.345172558059], [0.554558388074], [0.461898...
2017-08-02 16:43:00    [[0.689816890284], [0.613620822242], [0.389962...
...
#type(energy) = object
```

Comment: I know nothing about the signal processing but are you supplying any value to `x` when you actually calling `apply`. See here you are just writing a lambda expression but it will work when you actually call the function with real arguments like 5000 or something . May be you should show few more lines of your code.

Comment: @0decimal0 I'm not sure what you mean, but I was trying to do something similar to this: Quant25 = df.resample('30s').apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))
(which computes the first quartile for each time segment in df). I assumed the lambda function just takes as argument the subframe corresponding to the time segment at each iteration.

Comment: You need to show few more lines of code , how is lambda executed and all.

Comment: @0decimal0 The code appears exactly as written here. namely, the line `energy = x.resample('30S').apply(lambda x: (numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.fft(x))**2)/30)` appears immediately after the declaration of the dataframe x. Based on what you are saying it sounds like nothing should happen at all, but I do still receive the output and no error/warning.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the energy in the frequency domain - you can do it quite simply in the time domain (unless you are only interested in a subset of frequency bins of course) - see [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Applications).

Answer (score 4):

```
import scipy as sp

# Create input of real sine wave
fs = 1.0
fc = 0.25
n = sp.arange(0, 300)
x = sp.cos(2*sp.pi*n*fc/fs)

# Rearrange x into 10 30 second windows
x = sp.reshape(x, (-1, 30))

# Calculate power over each window [J/s]
p = sp.sum(x*x, 1)/x.size

# Calculate energy [J = J/s * 30 second]
e = p*x.size
```

Comment: Thanks! But why are we dividing by x.size and then multiplying again?

Comment: Also, how can I reshape an array which is not divisible by 30? I suppose the sensible thing to do would be to interpolate the remaining values, but how do I do it assuming I don't know the length of the array beforehand?

Comment: _p = sp.sum(x*x, 1)/x.size_ is calulating the average power over the 30 second window.  Since power is measured in _Joules/sec_ and energy is measured in _Joules_, _e = p*x.size_ integrates the power over the observation windos _J/s * s_ to get energy.

Comment: No, you cannot reshape the array if it's size is not divisible by 30.  Why not just zero pad the array to make size a multiple of 30.